# Low priority updates on MySQL using JDBC - how to check if they work

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I have a basic setup where the database is read by multiple web applications, and periodically I have a batch application which does a lot of writing. During the writing, the peroformance of the web-apps degrade heavily (their database reads are very slow).

The env. is MySQL db using MYISAM engine, the batch application is a Java SE app, using spring-batch and SimpleJDBCTemplate to issue SQL commands via JDBC. I found that MySQL has a parameter that lowers the priority of write operations on MYISAM engine: [low_priority_updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_low-priority-updates). To quote the docs, amongs others, you can "SET LOW_PRIORITY_UPDATES=1 to change the priority in one thread". I opted for this because it's easiest from the config standpoint of my application. What I've done is configured my DataSource such that it exectutes that "SET ..." for each connection it opens, like so:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- other props omitted -->
        <property name="connectionInitSqls">
            <list>
                <value>SET low_priority_updates="ON"</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now my question is, how do I actually check that an SQL issued via this datasource does actually run with low priority? If I do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in MySQL while the inserts are happening it just tell me what SQL they're executing, nothing about the priority:

[image]

If I check the server variables low_priority_updates is "OFF" but that's just the server variable, it sais nothing about the thread-local value.

So again, is there any actual way to check if per query/thread low_priority_updates's values are taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By issuing SET LOW_PRIORITY_UPDATES=1 command, you are affecting the variable value for the session. Therefore it is possible to see this by checking the value of the variable in the session.

I know of two ways to do it:

1- SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'low_priority_dapdates'

this shows ON/OFF

2- select @@session.low_priority_updates

this gives 0/1

**Important:** the above statements/calls will show you the values of the variables in the session where they run.
Therefore, you will need to run them using the connections themselves in order to see the values. I don't know of a way in MySQL where you can select values for variables that belong to another session.

If you would like to see them as a list, you might need to do a work around by creating a table and logging that info yourself. for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`my_low_priority_updates` (
  `connection_id` INT ,
  `low_priority_updates_value` INT  NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

then you need a statement that inserts the connection id and the value into the table:

```
insert into my_low_priority_updates(connection_id,low_priority_updates_value)
select connection_id(),@@session.low_priority_updates
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from my_low_priority_updates where connection_id=connection_id())
```

you can put this statement in a procedure and make sure its called, or add it in a trigger on a table that you know gets updated/inserted into.

after that, querying the my_low_priority_updates table later will show you the values of the variable in each connection.

Comment: Yep, it worked out great. I can use JDBC to check that a connection has the correct low_priority_value by issuing 'select connection_id(),@@session.low_priority_updates
from dual'. And indeed it works ok, the session value of the variable changes according to how I initialize it at connection init. Thanks!